# How to find child references for a specific entity record?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I can only distinguish parent references based on the data from the entity record I have retrieved. The question is
how to list all child references for a specific entity record?

I have an account entity and I want to find all related child entities (contacts ... etc) using REST API.

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: I have an Account and want to find all related entities (contacts .. etc), not parent entities, only children

Comment: query the metadata to find the relationships and after query the relationships

Comment: How are you fetching the records? Javascript?C#? Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code to retrieve related child entities for parent:

```
function RetrieveRelatedChildEntities() {
   var url = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl()  + "/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')?$select=LogicalName,DisplayCollectionName&$expand=ManyToManyRelationships,ManyToOneRelationships,OneToManyRelationships";
   req.open("GET", url, false);
   req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
   req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
   req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
   req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
   req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);

            for (var i = 0; i < results.OneToManyRelationships.length; i++) {
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```